# Form builder in Rails for end users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Is there a rails application that allows users to generate forms like you would see in a CMS or stackforms?  Something similar to a survey app where the user picks each field and whether its a text, drop down, email, checkbox etc and it creates a form on their site and an admin to view the results, edit them, etc.

Comment: FYI another example of this in the wild is www.Wufoo.com.